# Margin isn't working in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am making UI for a game. When I tried to put margin for the image tab.png

It doesn't reflect any changes to it. It stays where it was before. I also tried to solve this problem by adding the margins through the Layout and by adding it outside the rectangle and row layout but nothing happened.
 Also when I am adding margin to the bottom to the user.png to shift it a bit upward, it isn't shifting. So please help me out to solve this. I want to position the tab.png as this layout

[image]

The second circle is where I want to place the tab.png. The output of the code

[image]

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Main screen")
    ColumnLayout{
        spacing: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            id: titlebar
            Layout.preferredHeight: 60
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            RowLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 0

                Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    color: "black"
                    Image {

                        source: "qrc:/img/tab.png"
                        anchors.leftMargin: undefined
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                    }


                }
                Rectangle {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    color: "#f46b42"
                    /*Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Actions"
                    }*/


                    Image{
                        id:image_user


                        source: "qrc:/img/user.png"

                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.verticalCenterOffset:
                        anchors.left=parent.left
                        anchors.leftMargin: 10

                        clip: true

                    }

                     Item{
                         id:text_content
                         anchors.centerIn: parent
                         anchors.bottomMargin: 20
                        Text{
                        id:text_user
                        text: "User"
                        anchors.bottom:text_value.top
                        anchors.bottomMargin: 4


                    }
                    Text{
                        id:text_value


                        text:"$ 2000"
                        color:"yellow"


                     }}
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id:  content
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "lightyellow"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent

            }
            Column{
                spacing: 1;
                Repeater{
                    id:mmm
                    model: 5

                    Rectangle{
                        id:imgl
                        width: 100
                        height: 100


                        color: "#4286f4"
                        property string src: ""
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill:parent
                            onClicked: {
                                parent.color="";
                            }
                        }


                        Image {
                            id: imgx

                            source: parent.src;
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                            }
                        onParentChanged: {
                            mmm.itemAt(0).src="qrc:/img/5by90.png";
                            mmm.itemAt(1).src="qrc:/img/6by42.png";
                            mmm.itemAt(2).src="qrc:/img/12by24.png";
                            mmm.itemAt(3).src="qrc:/img/fortune.png";
                            mmm.itemAt(4).src="qrc:/img/mini-roulette.png";

                        }


                    }

                }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layouts only affect your direct children, not the children of the children., so `Layout.leftMargin: 20` will not affect Image as you see in this case.

The solution is really simple, it establishes the property `x: 20` since the position of item is with respect to the parent's topleft position

```
Rectangle {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    color: "black"
    Image { 
        x:20
        source: "qrc:/img/tab.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside Rectangle, for child elements, you need to use `anchors.margin`, whereas for Layouts child element can use `Layout.margin`.You need to use **anchors.leftMargin:** as Parent is Rectangle, `Layout.margin` will not have any effect.

```
Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    color: "black"
                    Image {

                        source: "qrc:/img/tab.png"
                        anchors.leftMargin: 20
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Without left anchoring `Image` to parent .. `anchors.leftMargin` will have no effect